# Rails Console "sharing" CTRL + C

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I open two Rails consoles and press CTRL+C in one of them, it will be sent to both consoles.

Why is that and how can I prevent this?

(Rails 4.2.0)

Comment: We're going to need more info.  Operating system, terminal app, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm using Mac and Terminal.app. When I log into consoles with two terminals to one Ubuntu server and press CTRL+C I will the same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4.1 introduced [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring), which speeds up the booting process of some Rails' components (like the console).

Each console is now trying to reach the spring server to check whether or not an existing Rails app is already running. If it finds one, it does a "warm run" as there's no need to boot the app.

Hitting Ctrl+C sends the `SIGINT` signal to Spring (and you can see `^C` on all your terminals running a console connected to that server) but [Spring ignore them to avoid killing the master server](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/8a75bfd7225d2ccdf6c9cbd6a8655a89f232ceac/lib/spring/server.rb#L81).

AFAICT from this analysis, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I'm unsure if I understood, are you saying that there is nothing that can be done against this? Thanks for your input

Comment: just added a conclusion to my post: no you can't do anything about this :-(

Comment: I'm speechless, so it's effectively impossible to use more than 1 console simultaneously in Rails 4? And this compromise just for a little faster startup times? I can't believe that. Or, is there another way than CTRL+C/Z to abort a console?

Comment: Ctrl+D would just work fine in your case. It's totally possible to use more than 1 console. What you see if you a side-effect of what's in place to prevent an accidental termination of the spring server AFAIK.

Comment: I will just go with DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails console

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Benedikt B:

- First kill spring:

`spring stop`

- Re-start the separates/long-running processes you don't want to be killed:

`DISABLE_SPRING=1 rake some_long_running_task`

`DISABLE_SPRING=1 rake some_other_long_running_task`

`DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails c # some console you don't start very often`

- Start your rails server/console with spring:

`rails s # main server`

`rails c # main console`

In my experience, this setup works fine.