# Why ctrl + z and ctrl + c is not working on Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I know `Control+z` is used for suspending a process by sending it the signal SIGSTOP.
Whenever I run the `rails console` command it goes to the console and show me this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)  
2.2.1 :001 >
```

This means I am in rails console.
But when I use ctrl+z to come out of console This appears:

```
[1]+  Stopped
```

which means console process is stopped successfully.

**The problem is**: When I use the Ubuntu terminal then it sends me to the Console and shows me:

```
 xyz:~/Desktop/x/y$ rails c  
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)  
    2.2.1 :001 >  
    [1]+  Stopped                 rails c  
    xyz:~/Desktop/x/y$ cd ..  
    2.2.1 :002 >
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Stopped which means console process is stopped successfully.

This is wrong. `ctrl-z`, doesn't stop a process. It sends it to the background in a paused state. However as you can see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447589/rails-console-sharing-ctrl-c), it also starts a separate "spring server" which you aren't pausing when you send the console process to the background. This can cause strange behaviour since the spring server believes there are two consoles running now.

If you actually want to exit the rails console properly, use `ctrl-d` which is a clean shutdown.

Comment: So why is a background process in a 'paused state' (aka 'stopped' or 'suspended') interacting negatively with the current console? How can it be fixed/resolved?

Comment: exactly then why is it interacting while it is in paused state..??